# phpMyAdmin database is connected but not inserting data

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a Wedding Planning Web Application. My Database is connected but no data is being inserted nor am I receiving any error messages when trying to register a user.

I'm being directed straight to the linked Login page. I've tried to match the date formatting (User input as `dd/mm/yyyy` and being stored as yyyy/mm/dd) from php and MySQL but not sure if it's working/ if it is the issue.

I've been trying to figure out a solution for hours and I'm under pressure to solve it so I can complete my dissertation.

```
<?php
    //Starts the session
    session_start();

    require_once 'DBConnect.php';

    $firstname = "";
    $lastname = "";
    $email_address = "";
    $phone_num = ""; 
    $acc_password = "";
    $weddingdate = "";

    // REGISTER USER
    if (isset($_POST['btn-Register'])) 
    {

        // receive all input values from the form
        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, $_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, $_POST['lastname']);
        $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, 
        $_POST['email_address']);

        $phone_num = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, $_POST['phone_num']);
        $acc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, 
        $_POST['acc_password']);

        $weddingdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, 
        $_POST['weddingdate']);

        // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
        // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
        // phone_num and weddingdate can be NULL
        if (empty($firstname)) { array_push($errors, "First Name is 
            required"); }
        if (empty($lastname)) { array_push($errors, "Last Name is 
            required"); }
        if (empty($email_address)) { array_push($errors, "Email is 
            required"); }
        if (empty($acc_password)) { array_push($errors, "Password is 
            required"); }


        // first check the database to make sure 
        // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
        $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email_address = 
        '$email_address' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        //if user exists
        if ($user['email_address'] === $email_address) 
        {
            array_push($errors, "User already exists");
        }

        // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) 
        {
            //encrypt the password before saving in the database
            $acc_password = md5($acc_password); 

            $query = "INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname, 
                      email_address, phone_num, acc_password, weddingdate) 
                     VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname' '$email_address', 
                      '$phone_num', '$acc_password', '$weddingdate')";
            mysqli_query($DBcon, $query);
            $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now Registered";
            header('location: Login.php');
        }

        //This should format the date with phpMyAdmin 
        $weddingdate = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($_POST["weddingdate"])); 

        // LOGIN USER
        if (isset($_POST['btn-Login'])) 
        {
            $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, 
            $_POST['email_address']);

            $acc_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon, 
            $_POST['acc_password']);

            if (empty($email_address)) 
            {
                array_push($errors, "Email Address is required");
            }
            if (empty($acc_password)) 
            {
                array_push($errors, "Password is required");
            }

            if (count($errors) == 0) 
            {
                $acc_password = md5($acc_password);

                $query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE 
                email_address='$email_address' AND 
                acc_password='$acc_password'";

                $results = mysqli_query($DBcon, $query);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['email_address'] = $email_address;
                    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
                    header('location: Main.php');
                }else 
                {
                    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password 
                    combination");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: Avoid using MD5 and use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: `mysqli` does not throw errors like PHP errors do. You need to check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way to make sure everything is working correctly.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Storing `yyyy/mm/dd` ? MySQL expects dates in a DATE or DATETIME column to be `YYYY-MM-DD` So are you using a VARCHAR to hold your dates? If so DONT

Comment: _Small Note_ `phpMyAdmin` is a tool ... MySQL is a database

Comment: Looks like you're formatting the date in a way that the database will like, and assigning it to a variable, **after** you're running the INSERT query?

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in `insert` query line.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname, email_address, phone_num, acc_password, weddingdate) 
 VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email_address', '$phone_num', '$acc_password', '$weddingdate')";
```

One Comma `,` is missing after `'$lastname'`

Comment: Thanks for that, just fixed it. Although, I think the issue is that the data isn't posting. I insert information into those fields but it's not posting into the database. Have you any idea why this would be??

Comment: you need to echo the query and then copy and paste in SQL console of phpmyadmin. There it will show exact error. or you may post here too I can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that the variables aren't being taken as their values. You need to escape the sequence before you can add the variables. So, instead of having

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname, 
                  email_address, phone_num, acc_password, weddingdate) 
                 VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email_address', 
                  '$phone_num', '$acc_password', '$weddingdate')";
```

You need to do this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO customer (firstname, lastname, email_address,
                 phone_num, acc_password, weddingdate) VALUES(
                 '" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "',
                 '" . $email_address . "', '" . $phone_num . "', 
                 '" . $acc_password . "', '" . $weddingdate . "')";
```

This should fix your problem, but as a few of the other commenters have mentioned, this may leave you open to SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements to protect yourself from those vulnerabilities.